# Python plotting libraries

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

What alternatives are there to pylab for plotting in Python? In particular, I'm looking for something that doesn't use the stateful model that [pylab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib) does.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can always use the object-oriented framework for [Matplotlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib) instead of the pylab interface.

Answer (score 48):

[Plotly](https://plotly.com/) lets you make graphs using a [Python API](https://plotly.com/graphing-libraries/), [matplotlib](https://plotly.com/python/matplotlib-to-plotly-tutorial/), and [pandas](https://plotly.com/ipython-notebooks/big-data-analytics-with-pandas-and-sqlite/). Their [IPython gallery](https://plotly.com/ipython-notebooks/) has some example scientific graphs with the Python scripts that generated them.

Here's a sample:

[image]

### Some recent exciting open source offerings:

- [ggplot](https://github.com/yhat/ggpy) is based on R's ggplot2, with aesthetically pleasing defaults and a really concise api. **wants to be a matplotlib killer**

[image: ggplot example]

- [bokeh](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/) makes interactive (html canvas) plots. **emphasis on interativity + handling big data**

[image: bokeh example]

- [vega](https://github.com/vega/vega) translates JSON "plot descriptions" into **SVG or Canvas-based interactive plots**, and [vincent](https://github.com/wrobstory/vincent) is a declarative interface for generating the JSON specifications.

[image: vega example]
<sub>(source: [fastly.net](https://github-camo.global.ssl.fastly.net/cf082a202b608048a1e5160f97eaa0597fd38e74/687474703a2f2f74726966616374612e6769746875622e636f6d2f766567612f696d616765732f626172312e706e67))</sub>

Comment: ggplot isn't trying to be a matplotlib killer...in fact it is a matplotlib wrapper.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend Bokeh. Tried it and it renders into a browser. In my opinion, that's lame. Should've just rendered it into it's own window. Besides, the plot didn't show up on Firefox and Chromium.

Answer (score 30):

There is a [list of Python-based plotting tools](http://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific/Plotting) on the [Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/).

Answer (score 3):

I have used [Gnuplot.py](http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/) with great success.

Answer (score 3):

I was in need of gnuplot interface for Python 3 but have found nothing. So I have ported Gnuplot.py to it.
See more info in the 'readme' of the [[repository]](https://github.com/oblalex/gnuplot.py-py3k). Hope this will help someone else in future.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a old program for automating the reading, filtering, processing, interpolation and plot n-dimensional values from different sources (like libreOffice- or csv-files) and variable size:
[diaGrabber](http://radjkarl.github.io/diaGrabber/).

You have to use some simple python-commands to create a case. After this you can manipulate the graphical output in an interactive [GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfCMH.png).

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple [gplot](http://pyla.codeplex.com)

Comment: pyla-gplot is a small stand alone single python script works with python 3 and above and Gnu plot.

Comment: to get gplot from pyla visit http://pyla.codeplex.com/; It needs Python 3 and Gnuplot 4.0 and above. Gnuplot.py by this date is not compatible with Python 3.x

Answer (score 1):

[MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) is free (GPL) plotting library with large set of graphics types, and have Python interface too (also can use numpy arrays).