# How to plot bar chart with data and convert it into image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to create the bar chart with some date information, After plotting the bar chart, I want to convert it into image. **Please tell me which python library should I use.**

I got the library plotly, I want to use to plot the graph,
link: [Python plotting libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915940/python-plotting-libraries)

**But How I will convert plotted graph into image.**

I want to generate image like following, based on the some information

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use matplotlib? Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/save-plot-to-image-file-instead-of-displaying-it-using-matplotlib-so-it-can-be)

In plotly check this: https://plot.ly/python/static-image-export/

P.S. I think plotly is useful for webapp, in your case the easy way is matplotlib.